# Derivation of power series to finding the radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm struggling with understanding derivatives of sum when finding radius of convergence and would appreciate some help.

I want to find the radius of convergence for the following power series.
$$
1 + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{2k} 
$$
which I've solved with just applying ratio test, but the exercise states that it should be done with the derivative of the power series which gives me
$$
1 + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k 2k \frac{x^{2k-1}}{2k} 
= 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k x^{2k-1}, 
$$
form here on I would like to substitute $2k-1$ with something, but I would like to think that this of solving the exercise is more complicated?

Would anyone like to explain why I would be better of with this way of solving it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your sums should begin at $k=1$ because of the $\frac1{2k}.$

Comment: Are you ok with the fact that the radius of convergence of a power series is the same as that of its derivative?

Comment: The "$1+$" should disappear in the derivative.

Comment: The method of the exercise may be considered as "better" if you already know the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n,$ which does not require the ratio test. But on the other hand, that ratio test is the easiest way to prove that the radius of convergence of a power series is the same as that of its derivative.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with the derivative and with the bounds for the summation (your general term doesn't make sense for $k=0$). If
$$
f(x)=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k}}{2k}
$$
then
$$
f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k x^{2k-1}
$$
because constant terms have zero derivative.

Now, for $x\ne0$, you have $f'(x)=g(-x^2)/x$ where
$$
g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k
$$
which has radius of convergence $1$, being a standard geometric series.

Thus your series converges when $|x^2|<1$, which is the same as $|x|<1$.

By the way, you now know that
$$
g(x)=\dfrac{x}{1-x}
$$
and therefore, for $x\ne0$,
$$
f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}\frac{-x^2}{1+x^2}=-\frac{x}{1+x^2}
$$
which also holds for $x=0$. Thus
$$
f(x)=c-\log(\sqrt{1+x^2}\,)
$$
and you can determine $c$ by observing that $f(0)=1$.